# MS SQL: Should ISDATE() Return "1" when Cannot Cast as Date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

everyone,

On a SQL Server instance running 2012 SP3, the following code returns "1":

```
SELECT ISDATE('january,25,1999')
```

However, the following fails the conversion:

```
SELECT CAST('january,25,1999' AS DATE)

Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Am I misunderstanding what ISDATE() ought to return? Why does ISDATE() return a value of "1" for the string? How ought we determine, from SQL Server, whether strings such as "january,25,1999" can be casted as dates?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe `BEGIN TRY` block will help.

Comment: `ISDATE` is the *slightly* more sane cousin of `ISNUMERIC`, but they both lead you into the same trap - "can this string be converted to any date/numeric data type, I don't care which?" - in this case, it can be converted to `datetime`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever . . . Why can it be converted to a `datetime`, but not a `date`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - don't have a solid answer other than the fact that they did seem to clean up a lot of the silly/unexpected conversions when you work with the new data types compared to `datetime`. E.g. the assumption that someone in the UK would be using a `YYYY-DD-MM` format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Forget `ISDATE()`!  You are using SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(date, 'january,25,1999')
```

This will return `NULL` if the date cannot be converted -- which I don't think this can be.  You can specify a third argument for the particular format you want to convert.

I will note something that in SQL Server 2014:

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(date, 'january,25,1999')
```

returns an error.

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(datetime, 'january,25,1999')
```

succeeds.

I have no idea why.  But for what you want:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, TRY_CONVERT(datetime, 'january,25,1999'))
```

Comment: Both date and datetime return NULL for me

Comment: @Jonny . . . I doubt this functionality changed from 2012 to 2014.  Could you have other characters in the string that are not visible?

Comment: @Jonny - what is the default language of your login? e.g. see `set language english;SELECT TRY_CONVERT(datetime, 'january,25,1999');set language italian;SELECT TRY_CONVERT(datetime, 'january,25,1999')`

Comment: Thank you! This is great, exactly what we need. 

We also have a SQL Server 2008 R2 server we develop on (yes, yes, I know, and I accept your scolding), and we won't be able to take this approach on it. Maybe we'll use that as an incentive to get the server upgraded. If you happen to know a good 2008 R2 solution, I'd appreciate it, but I know from the outset that it's out of mainstream support.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use CONVERT, not CAST, to parse dates from non-standard string formats.

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, 'january,25,1999')
```

will give you a SQL Server datetime containing 1999-01-25 00:00:00.000

Comment: @Jonny . . . It does work in SQL Server 2014.  It does not work with `date`, but it does work with `datetime`.

Answer (score 0):

As regards the 2008R2 part...
The issue I found with the ISDATE function is

-- my valid date dd/mm/yy stored as a char
Select ISDATE('dd/mm/yy') returns zero unless you convert to a date

Select ISDATE(convert(date,'dd/mm/yy',103).. say

,but, then as a consequence this returns an error when the convert evaluates a non-date field.

The way around this is to first run

SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
(assume this is scoped to the proc but may not be?)

then ISDATE('dd/mm/yy') should return 1