# SQL Server - Value passes ISDATE() but fails to CAST as DATE or DATETIME

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, type-conversion

I have a `varchar` column in my database table, on the row I would like to return it is populated as '`2018-12-26T00:00:00.000`' (quotes mine, not included in actual value). When I try to query for this value whenever it is a valid date, e.g.

```
SELECT
    myValue
FROM 
    myTable
WHERE
    ISDATE(myValue) = 1
```

it returns properly. However, I need this value to be converted to `DATE`. When I try something like this:

```
SELECT
    CAST(myValue AS DATE) AS myValueFormatted
FROM 
    myTable
WHERE
    ISDATE(myValue) = 1
```

I get an error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Is there any other way I can convert this `varchar` value to `Date`?

UPDATE: I've noticed through trying some different things, the query seems to be fine with me using the value as a date for anything (`DATEDIFF`, `CONVERT` back to string, etc.) in the select portion, but trying to do anything with it in the `WHERE` clause causes the error. To ensure nothing else is interfering, I created a temp table with only 1 row with the data value above, and running the query just against that one value gives the error

UPDATE 2: Ok, I have no idea why this fixes it, but this is what I found. When I run

```
SELECT
    myValue
FROM
    myTable
WHERE
    TRY_CONVERT(DATE, myValue) IS NOT NULL
```

it returns EXACTLY the same values as

```
SELECT
    myValue
FROM 
    myTable
WHERE
    ISDATE(myValue) = 1
```

However, when I then add `AND CAST(myValue AS DATE) < GETDATE()` to each `WHERE` clause, only the first one works. I understand why TRY_CONVERT is safer to use, I'm still not sure why it works over GETDATE()

Comment: Use TRY_CONVERT to find the exact row as it appears you might have some dodgy data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS SQL: Should ISDATE() Return "1" when Cannot Cast as Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41896959/ms-sql-should-isdate-return-1-when-cannot-cast-as-date)

Comment: or a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49867586/try-parse-vs-try-convert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't reproduce your error...

`declare @dt varchar(256) = '2018-12-26T00:00:00.000'
select cast(@dt as date)`

So, there must be another rogue value in there that can't be converted.

To identify what value is causing the issue on versions < 2012, run this:

```
SELECT
myValue
FROM myTable
WHERE
ISDATE(myValue) = 0
```

Note, `ISDATE` is deterministic only if you use it with the `CONVERT` function, if the `CONVERT` style parameter is specified, and style is not equal to 0, 100, 9, or 109.

For 2012 onward, use [`TRY_CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
SELECT
*
FROM myTable
WHERE
TRY_CONVERT(date, myValue) IS NULL
```

Comment: The TRY_CONVERT helped me track down what was going on. Thanks!

Comment: ...actually while I did find a value that was wonky and removed it, it still seems to have the problem :(

Comment: If you run the second query, you'd find *all* rows that have the issue. Did it only return one?

Comment: After removing the row that didn't work there were no more rows returned by the query

Comment: Ok, what query did you run that posed the problem after you fixed the issue? Can you add that to the post with the sample data that's causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could also just try something like this:

```
SELECT CAST(LEFT(MyValue, 10) AS DATE)
```

If it still doesn't work, you have some formatting issues with your data.

Comment: Unfortunately it gave the same error with that in the where clause, though it works fine as part of the SELECT statement. The only row I am returning is the one with the value above

Answer (score 0):

This helped me....

CAST string as varchar(30) then cast the varchar as datetime2

CAST(CAST(REPLACE(['Timestamp' ],'''','') AS varchar(30)) as datetime2)

Comment: why we need to replace anything? is it a datetime or not?